# how to create copy of hash-map object without effecting the original object value

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I'm trying to make a hashmap object and assign it's value from another hashmap but I found the changes on the copy effected the orignal object values

how I can make the copy not effects the original?

here is my code

```
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> productOfferLimitsForCart = new HashMap<>();
  productOfferLimitsForCart .put(Integer.valueOf(liveModel.getId()), 0);

  HashMap<Integer, Integer> OfferLimitsForCalculations = new HashMap<>();
  OfferLimitsForCalculations = productOfferLimitsForCart;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the copy constructor:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> OfferLimitsForCalculations = new HashMap<>(productOfferLimitsForCart);
```

When you make the assignment

```
OfferLimitsForCalculations = productOfferLimitsForCart;
```

both variables are referencing the same `HashMap` instance (and the original `Map` that was referenced by `OfferLimitsForCalculations` is no longer referenced by any variable).

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the entries from an existing map using the putAll() function.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> productOfferLimitsForCart = new HashMap<>();
productOfferLimitsForCart .put(Integer.valueOf(liveModel.getId()), 0);

HashMap<Integer, Integer> OfferLimitsForCalculations = new HashMap<>();
OfferLimitsForCalculations.putAll(productOfferLimitsForCart);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a copy you're creating. You're just assigning it a second name.

You can create a swallow copy by calling `OfferLimitsForCalculations.putAll(productOfferLimitsForCart);`

This creates a new map but with the same objects inside. So if you operate on the objects inside one map you're still changing the contents of the second map. But with just Integers this should not be an issue because usually Integers are effectively final.